# Why isn't this allowed in C#?

Tags: c#

I have the following if condition `param.days` is a string.

```
if (param.days != null)
```

This works fine, but if I say

```
If (param.days)
```

then it does not evaluate correctly at runtime. Both statements are not the same in C#.
**It does say that the value is null but then C# tries to cast it to a bool which is non-nullable.**
***Why did the C# designers choose to do it this way?***
Such a statement is valid in C++, but why is this not considered valid in C#?

Comment: null isn't a boolean

Comment: What is the type of `param.days`?

Comment: @Sayse: Yes I get that, but is there any other reason for this not being evaluated correctly. Or is it because bool is a non-nullable type and so there is no other way out.

Comment: ["The if statement selects a statement for execution based on the value of a Boolean expression"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) - Maybe I don't understand your question

Comment: "is valid in C++, but why is this not considered valid in C#" - because they're different languages? If everything behaved the same between different languages with a superficial resemblance, multiple languages wouldn't exist.

Comment: Hey guys, why the downvotes? The answer is trivial to anyone familiar with C#, but not everyone is familiar with C#.

Comment: I haven't downvoted but as my previous comment shows, its really easy to find out why by looking in documentation

Comment: Language variations are definitely the reason but is there any specific reason for this being the case?

Comment: Probably because the person asking downvoted every answer in the thread. Probably because it's trivial, in that c# requires a boolean with an `IF` statement. His question should really be `Why doesn't c# cast an int to a boolean automatically` and I think the answer is fairly apparent when you think about it.

Comment: @ckv Is this asking why technically (as in, bool evaluation) or why as a design choice does C# not support this looser evaluation?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Specifically the design aspect.

Comment: @ckv Very few people can answer the "why" without conjecture, fortunately some of them do frequent SO.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Such a statement is valid in C++, but why is this not considered valid in C#

Because C# assumes different languange rules. It does not assume that every number / reference can be treated as a boolean by checking if it is zero vs non-zero, null vs non-null. If you want to test whether something is null: *test whether it is null*.

Note: if `days` is actually a `T?` (aka `Nullable<T>`), then you can check:

```
if(param.days.HasValue)
```

which is then identical to `if(param.days != null)`

Alternatively, if your type *can* sensibly be treated as a boolean, then there are operators you can override to tell the compiler that.

Answer (score 6):

C# unlike C++, does not implicitly cast integer to bool.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>To clarify, this is answering the question amendment in the comments: why did the C# designers choose not to implement null to boolean evaluation whereas C++ allows it.</sub>

Taken from Eric Lippert's post "[null is not false](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/03/26/null-is-not-false.aspx)":

> Some languages allow null values of value types or reference types, or
> both, to be implicitly treated as Booleans.
>
> And similarly for nullable value types; in some languages a null value
> type is implicitly treated as "false".
>
> The designers of C# considered those features and rejected them.
> First, because treating references or nullable value types as Booleans
> is a confusing idiom and a potential rich source of bugs. And second,
> because semantically it seems presumptuous to automatically translate
> null -- which should mean "this value is missing" or "this value is
> unknown" -- to "this value is logically false".

This particular sentence covers your `string` example, but nothing of other types having implicit boolean evaluation.

However, one might surmise the reason for items such as integers not evaluating to boolean also falls under the banner of being a poor idiom or too presumptuous.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, the `If` statement requires the contents of the brackers to be a boolean expression.

Consider `If ("Hello World")`.

Is "Hello World" true or false? It's neither, it's a string.

You may want to consider a LINQ expression such as `.Any()` for example, `If (myListOfCats.Any())` as your .days property implies a collection of objects.

Comment: That's a terrible example since `if ("Hello World")` will compile in C++. The question asks about the difference between C++ and C#, so this doesn't really answer it.

Comment: It's not `C++`, it's `C#`

Comment: @Dukeling You could argue the question is actually asking why C# doesn't support syntax that is possible in C++, not necessarily the differences between them.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Well, that is exactly what the question is asking. Whether it be from a design or technical point of view, this essentially still comes down to the difference between the two (in my opinion). This answer essentially just gives another example, except for the first paragraph (if the answer was *just* that, it would've probably been better, not enough for an upvote, but better).

Comment: @Dukeling I wasn't attempting to defend the answer, I was just highlighting that I interpreted the question differently to you. I saw it as "why did the C# designers choose to do this" as opposed to any comparison with C++.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison in the if statement needs to evaluate to a boolean result. param.days is not a boolean. You need to compare the value to null to get a boolean result. C# is type safe.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison in the `if` statement requires to a `boolean` result. `param.days` is `string`  not a `boolean`. C# does not implicitly cast `integer` to `bool`.

You need to compare the value to null or use `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` to get a `boolean` result
If you want to do so try this code:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.days))
 {
 }
```

OR

```
 if (param.days!=NULL)
 {
 }
```